# Remove weekends from an AChartEngine chart

Tags: android, achartengine

How do I remove weekends from an AChartEngine chart in Android? The chart is a combinedXYChartView with multpile TimeSeries, one represented with bars, the rest as lines.

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

You can add null values `MathHelper.NULL_VALUE` such as the line chart is interrupted during weekends.